# firebase throws error Uncaught Error: Reference.child failed:

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, undefined

i am trying to edit or delete a record from firebase.
I have successfully add and retrieve data to html page.
But during click of edit or delete button nothing happens and error comes up.
error:

> Uncaught Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

my js code is

```
//TABLE REFERENCE
const  empRef = firebase.database().ref('employee');
//$('#emp-table').find('tbody').html('');
var new_html = '';
//EDIT
$(document).on('click', '.editEmp', function () {
    var emp_id = $(this).attr('data-emp-id');
    
    empRef.child(emp_id).once('value').then(function (emp){
        var modal_header = '';

        modal_header += '<h4 class="modal-title">Add ' + emp.val().name + '</h4>';
        modal_header += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>';

        var modal_body = '';
        modal_body += '<div class="form-group">';
        modal_body += '<label>Name</label>';
        modal_body += '<input id="edit-name" type="text" value="'+emp.val().name+'" class="form-control" required>';
        modal_body += '</div>';
        modal_body += '<div class="form-group">';
        modal_body += '<label>Email</label>';
        modal_body += '<input type="email" id="edit-email" value="'+emp.val().email+'" class="form-control" required>';
        modal_body += '</div>';
        modal_body += '<div class="form-group">';
        modal_body += '<label>Address</label>';
        modal_body += '<textarea id="edit-address"  class="form-control" required>'+emp.val().address+'</textarea>';
        modal_body += '</div>';
        modal_body += '<div class="form-group">';
        modal_body += '<label>Phone</label>';
        modal_body += '<input id="edit-phone" type="text" value="'+emp.val().phone+'" class="form-control" required>';
        modal_body += '</div>';
        

        var modal_footer = '';
        modal_footer += '<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">';
        modal_footer += '<input type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" data-emp-id="'+emp_id+'"  class="btn btn-danger updateEmpData" value="Save">';
        $("#editEmployeeModal").find('.modal-header').html(modal_header);
        $("#editEmployeeModal").find('.modal-body').html(modal_body);
        $("#editEmployeeModal").find('.modal-footer').html(modal_footer);
        $("#editEmployeeModal").modal();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `emp_id` is `undefined`, which is not allowed for Firebase.

You can catch this condition in your code with:

```
var emp_id = $(this).attr('data-emp-id');

if (emp_id) {
    empRef.child(emp_id).once('value').then(function (emp){
    ...
```

Also see these previous [questions about this error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bjavascript%5D+First+argument+was+an+invalid+path+undefined).

Comment: actually all the ids are generated dynamically. how to catch the id.

Comment: I have no idea what that means. All I can say from what you shared is that your `emp_id` is empty, which is not allowed. You can check for the empty value with the code in my answer.